# TLSharp exception in function ConnectAsync

Tags: c#, telegram

I compiled my console test application using latest version of TLSharp and now I have got exception in DeserializeObject function line 24 while calling ConnectAsync function. As far as I understand from debugging in some moment to the function TLContext.getType(Constructor) the value -1704251862 is passed. This is old Constructor value for TLConfig object and I completely can not understand where application get it from. In sources of the TLSharp library this value is absent. I recreated session.dat file but it didn't help. Plesase, help me, because my current project in big trouble now. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TeleSharp.TL.Messages;
using TLSharp.Core;


namespace SendPhotoTest
{
    public class GetPhotoTester
    {
    FileSessionStore _sessionStore = new FileSessionStore();
    static string registeredPhone = "+7985XXXXXXX";
    static int apiID = XXXXX;
    static string apiHash = "49d60ed8bd78533986e05e3ffb60b443";
    static string code = "XXXXX";
    TelegramClient client;

    class Assert
    {
        static internal void IsNotNull(object obj)
        {
            IsNotNullHanlder(obj);
        }

        static internal void IsTrue(bool cond)
        {
            IsTrueHandler(cond);
        }
     }

    internal static Action<object> IsNotNullHanlder;
    internal static Action<bool> IsTrueHandler;

    protected void Init(Action<object> notNullHandler, Action<bool> trueHandler)
    {
        IsNotNullHanlder = notNullHandler;
        IsTrueHandler = trueHandler;

        // Setup your API settings and phone numbers in app.config
        //GatherTestConfiguration();
     }

    public GetPhotoTester()
    {
        client = CreateClient();
        InitializeAndAuthenticateClient(client, 0).Wait();
    }

    public TelegramClient CreateClient()
    {
        TelegramClient clt = null;

        //clt = new TelegramClient(apiID, apiHash, _sessionStore, "C:\\Users\\hermann\\Documents\\session.dat");
        clt = new TelegramClient(apiID, apiHash);

        return clt;
    }

    public async Task InitializeAndAuthenticateClient(TelegramClient client, int mode = 1)
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync();

        var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(registeredPhone);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            throw new Exception("CodeToAuthenticate is empty in the app.config file, fill it with the code you just got now by SMS/Telegram");
        }

        TLUser user = null;
        try
        {
            user = await client.MakeAuthAsync(registeredPhone, hash, code);
        }
        catch (CloudPasswordNeededException ex)
        {
            var password = await client.GetPasswordSetting();
            var password_str = "PasswordToAuthenticate";

            user = await client.MakeAuthWithPasswordAsync(password, password_str);
        }
        catch (InvalidPhoneCodeException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("CodeToAuthenticate is wrong in the app.config file, fill it with the code you just got now by SMS/Telegram",
                                ex);
        }
        Assert.IsNotNull(user);
        Assert.IsTrue(client.IsUserAuthorized());
    }
```

And this is exception: "Constructor Invalid Or Context.Init Not Called !".
**UPD**
I'd like to add that this problem appeared after upgrade TLSharp to level 66.

Comment: It will help if you post the error message and the calling code.

Comment: I added my code and exception description

Answer (score 1):

I removed the "session.dat" from output folder and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a FakeSessionStore not FileSessionStore. Maybe your program takes the values from the file.